# How to change response_type on Spring OAuth2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

This is my configuration for OAuth2 login with Instagram

```
instagram:
  client:
    clientId: clientId
    clientSecret: clientSeret
    accessTokenUri: https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
    userAuthorizationUri: https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize
    clientAuthenticationScheme: form
  scope:
    - basic
    - public_content
  resource:
    userInfoUri: https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/
    delimiter: +
```

This is the request made by Spring:

https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=clientId&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login/instagram&response_type=code&state=CG6mMQ

How can I change the `response_type` to `&response_type=token` and how can I why isn't Spring adding the scopes?

Here is the App class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class App extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/"))
                // logout
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
                // CSRF
                .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                // filters
                .and().addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter() {
        CompositeFilter filter = new CompositeFilter();
        List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<>();

        // facebook ...
        // google ...

        // instagram
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter instagramFilter =
                new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter("/login/instagram");
        OAuth2RestTemplate instagramTemplate =
                new OAuth2RestTemplate(instagram(), oauth2ClientContext);
        instagramFilter.setRestTemplate(instagramTemplate);
        instagramFilter.setTokenServices(
                new UserInfoTokenServices(instagramResource().getUserInfoUri(), instagram().getClientId()));
        filters.add(instagramFilter);

        filter.setFilters(filters);
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("instagram.client")
    public AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails instagram() {
        return new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("instagram.resource")
    public ResourceServerProperties instagramResource() {
        return new ResourceServerProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean oauth2ClientFilterRegistration(
            OAuth2ClientContextFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(filter);
        registration.setOrder(-100);
        return registration;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I change the response_type to &response_type=token

As I read the code, `AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider‘s` response_type is hard code.

```
private UserRedirectRequiredException getRedirectForAuthorization(AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails resource,
            AccessTokenRequest request) {

        // we don't have an authorization code yet. So first get that.
        TreeMap<String, String> requestParameters = new TreeMap<String, String>();
        requestParameters.put("response_type", "code"); // oauth2 spec, section 3
```

So, If you want to change the response_code, you can extend the `AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider`, or implements the `AccessTokenProvider`, and then inject to the `OAuth2RestTemplate` `accessTokenProvider`(the default value is a `AccessTokenProviderChain` that contains `AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider`, `ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider` and so on, use your own provider instead of `AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider`).

Or you can change the `redirectStrategy` in `OAuth2ClientContextFilter`, and change the request param when redirect, but I don't recommend this.

> How can I why isn't Spring adding the scopes?

`AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider` will get scopes from `AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails`, and add them to `UserRedirectRequiredException`. I think the scope can't be injected to `AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails`, because the scope is not under the client. Maybe you need to change to this.

```
instagram:
  client:
    clientId: clientId
    clientSecret: clientSeret
    accessTokenUri: https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
    userAuthorizationUri: https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize
    clientAuthenticationScheme: form
    scope:
      - basic
      - public_content
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the query parameters from the `UserRedirectRequiredException`. So in the code which throws the exception and thus causes the redirect to happen, e.g. in your filter, you can do something like:

```
try {
    accessToken = restTemplate.getAccessToken();
}
catch (UserRedirectRequiredException e) {
    Map<String, String> requestParams = e.getRequestParams();
    requestParams.put("response_type", "token");

    throw e; //don't forget to rethrow
}
```

You can only replace values this way. If you needed to add a parameter value alongside an existing value, you'd need to use a delimiter such as '+'. There is no standard way of adding multiple parameter values and would depend on what the owner of the API accepts. Some APIs may not accept delimeters at all.