# What is the purpose of the implicit mode in Spring open id connect?

Tags: spring-security, openid-connect

I'm currently using the `Authorisation Code Flow` of openid connect in spring which is the default mode. In this mode, the response type used is `code` and I get an `access_token` and an `id_token`. So here, all seem ok.

But when I try to use the `Implicit Flow` by setting `authorizationGrantType=implicit` the response type used is `token` and I get only an `access_token`. This reflects the [Authorisation Request part of OAuth 2.0 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2.1). Moreover the `token` value for response type does not seems to be used by [OpenId Connect spec](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#CodeFlowSteps) :
[image: possible response types of openid connect]

So what is the purpose of the implicit mode in Spring open id connect ?

Comment: What is the Spring version you are using ? Also, can you give a code snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

> NOTE: While OAuth 2.0 also defines the **token** Response Type value for the Implicit Flow, OpenID Connect does not use this Response Type, since no ID Token would be returned.

As OpenID Connect specification highlights, **response_type=token** is not a valid response type for OpenID Connect. So what you are observing is falling back to OAuth 2.0 and hence receiving an access token.

I do not come from Spring background, but you should be able to define/configure the appropriate **response_type** values from your code. If this is not the case, you were merely lucky with Authorization code flow observation. Depending on authorization server configurations/preference it may send an **id token**. For example, Azure AD sends id token for [OAuth 2.0 code grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#successful-response-1)

Comment: It's not possible to define or configure the response_type in spring security. The response type is driven by a parameter `authorizationGrantType` which can take only two value `authorization_code` or `implicit`. In the first case `response_type=code` and in the secound case `response_type=token`. It seems to me incredible (funny ?) that Azure AD returns an id_token in the OAut 2.0 code grant. Indeed the id_token  never appears in the [OAut 2.0 specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749). I can not imagine that the smooth running of this flow depends of a hack of the provider.

Comment: @Fabrice I came across this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41208178/how-to-change-response-type-on-spring-oauth2 may be it will help you. Well regardless of specifications, in the real world as a fact, OpenID Connect and OAuth 2 implementations differ from implementation to implementation.